# Add donation to PayPal shopping cart?

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart, donations

Can I add a Donate button as one of the multiple items for PayPal's Add To Cart option?
A quick Google search seems to indicate the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

That is correct you can not have a Donate button as part of a Cart. However, you can have a donation item that can be added to your cart.

An example would be [A Theatre Group's](http://www.atheatregroup.org/donate/donate.php) donation page. The Left button is a Donate button, the Right button leads to a page with 3 types of donations and optional membership levels which are submitted to PayPal as a Cart.

If you click the standard Donate Button on the left, you go straight to PayPal to make a $10 donation.
If you use the right button, fill in any of the fields an click update, the fields are validated and then you can click the PayPal button to send the cart information to PayPal.

Comment: Yes the domain has been totally change sense 2013.